# как по радио кнопки вывести определенный гороскоп для каждого знака зодиака

Tags: javascript, html, дата, dom

никак не могу реализовать радиокнопки, чтобы при нажатие одну из радиокнопок выводился гороскоп на определенный день учитывая какой гороскоп соответствует дате введенной пользователем, пытался внутри сравнения по дате добавить условие которое отслеживает в каком состояние(checked) находится радиокнопка true/false, но все без успешно, также выводил отдельно условие, но не понимаю как связать со знаком зодиака, мало того, что код бы получился огромный, так еще и не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать данное задание, приложу полностью описание всех задач(3 пункта).

1. Продумайте, как вы будете хранить гороскопы в соответствии с поставленной задачей.
2. Реализуйте показ гороскопа за текущий день.
3. А теперь реализуйте работу радиокнопок, позволяющих выбрать день, за который нужно показать гороскоп.

```js
'use strict';

let infoDate = document.querySelector('.info-date'); //получние месяца и дня
let znakZodiac = document.querySelector('.znakZodiac'); //знак зодиака

let todayInfo = document.querySelector('.today-info'); //гороскоп на текущий день 
let yesterdayInfo = document.querySelector('.yesterday-info'); //гороскоп вчерашнего дня
let tomorrowInfo = document.querySelector('.tomorrow-info'); //гороскоп на завтрашений день

let infoHoroscop1 = document.querySelectorAll('#info1'); //чекбокс вчера
let infoHoroscop2 = document.querySelectorAll('#info2'); //чекбокс сегодня
let infoHoroscop3 = document.querySelectorAll('#info3'); //чекбокс завтра
let button = document.querySelector('button'); //пытался через кнопку осуществить показ гороскоп на выбранный день


//объект с гороскопом на вчера, завтра, сегодня, 
let horoscopesObject = {
    Aries: [ //Овен
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Вы быстро справитесь со сложными делами. Браться за них стоит как можно раньше, ведь именно утром поддержка звезд будет особенно заметной. Наверняка найдутся люди, готовые помочь вам, поделиться опытом или подсказать, как лучше действовать. Вероятны предложения о сотрудничестве. Если их сделают те, с кем вы прежде уже работали, можно ответить согласием без долгих раздумийДень обещает приятные знакомства.Будет возможность увидеться с теми, о ком вы раньше много слышали.Легко будет произвести хорошее впечатление: просто ведите себя естественно.Едва ли кто- то сможет противостоять вашему обаянию.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет насыщенным, непростым и интересным. Появится много новых дел, и для того, чтобы с ними справиться, вам придется потрудиться. Но никакие преграды не заставят вас бросить начатое, отказаться от задуманного. Настойчивость, которую вы будете проявлять в течение всего дня, привлечет внимание окружающим и очень им понравится. Не исключено, что в конце дня вам предложат что-то интересное. Старайтесь не переутомляться. На вечер лучше не планировать ничего особенно сложного. Отвлекитесь от забот, отдохните немного. Вы сразу почувствуете себя лучше.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Не спешите делиться своими идеями или делать критические замечания, о которых вас не просили. Сегодня особенно важно не говорить лишнего, ведь сказанное может быть использовано против вас. В остальном же день благоприятен. Он обещает приятные сюрпризы и новые возможности. Будет шанс осуществить то, что еще недавно казалось чрезвычайно сложным. Как бы ни были вы заняты сегодня, постарайтесь найти время для общения с близкими. Участвуйте в семейных делах, старайтесь поддерживать родственников, которые в этом нуждаются.'
        }
    ],

    Taurus: [ //Телец
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'День подойдет для новых знакомств, встреч с людьми, на которых вы хотели бы произвести хорошее впечатление. Вы наверняка понравитесь даже тем, кто обычно очень требователен к окружающим, замечает только чужие недостатки. Интуиция подскажет, как правильно провести деловые переговоры, заручиться поддержкой влиятельных людей.  Вероятны денежные поступления, в том числе из неожиданных источников. Не исключены и дорогие подарки. Вечер будет особенно благоприятным для учебы. Вы мгновенно запомните все, что может пригодиться.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Сохраняйте спокойствие, что бы ни происходило вокруг. Этого будет достаточно, чтобы избежать трудностей и неприятностей, а также горячих споров, которые могли бы испортить отношения с окружающими. Действуйте осторожно, старайтесь не спешить. Позже вы не раз похвалите себя за предусмотрительность, проявленную сегодня.Важна разборчивость в контактах. Не доверяйте всем подряд. Делиться важной информацией стоит только с самыми близкими людьми. Именно они поддержат вас и придут на помощь, если потребуется.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Вас ждет беспокойный день. Лучше не рассчитывать на легкие успехи. Скорее всего, вам придется приложить усилия, чтобы достичь нужных результатов. Настойчивость будет особенно важна для тех, кто сегодня возьмется за что-то новое. Таким Тельцам придется не только преодолевать преграды, но и учиться на ходу. Будет непросто, но все получится. Хорошо пройдут деловые встречи, вы быстро поладите с потенциальными партнерами. Нетрудно будет и найти общий язык с близкими. Перемены к лучшему в романтических отношениях станут возможными, если вы проявите инициативу.'
        }
    ],

    Gemini: [ //Близнецы
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Будет возможность взяться за интересное дело, к которому долго не получалось приступить. Сегодня обстоятельства сложатся удачно, у вас будет достаточно времени, не возникнет непреодолимых преград, никто не станет вам мешать. Заметных успехов добьются Близнецы, которые занимаются коммерческой деятельностью: вероятны выгодные покупки и сделки. В первой половине дня стоит действовать быстро, а вот во второй лучше не горячиться и не спешить. Это время хорошо подойдет для семейных дел, общения с близкими. Можно принимать гостей.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Не стоит принимать всерьез мелкие недоразумения, которые могут возникнуть в начале дня. Ладить с окружающими в это время будет непросто, но вы не поддадитесь на провокации и найдете способ разрядить обстановку. Появятся неплохие идеи, касающиеся работы. Уже во второй половине дня вы сможете приступить к их реализации. Будет возможность исправить ошибки, допущенные раньше. Справившись с этим, вы почувствуете себя гораздо увереннее и свободнее. Вечер обещает приятное знакомство, которое может получить романтическое продолжение.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'День может показаться довольно утомительным. Вам придется заниматься и своими, и чужими делами, решать проблемы, возникшие по вине других людей. Нелегко придется Близнецам, которые привыкли действовать по-своему, ничего не объясняя и ни с кем не советуясь. Таким представителям знака нужно быть особенно терпеливыми с окружающими. Только так они смогут избежать конфликтов и споров. Первая половина дня будет довольно напряженной, вторая принесет хорошие новости. Скорее всего, они будут связаны с вашей личной жизнью.'
        }
    ],

    Сancer: [ //Рак
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Сегодня вам предстоит заниматься чем-то новым и необычным. Учиться придется на ходу, причем совершенно самостоятельно: едва ли кто-то направит вас на верный путь, даст полезный совет или подскажет, как лучше действовать. Первая половина дня обещает интересное знакомство, встречу с человеком, который вскоре станет вашим другом. Вторая половина дня подойдет для того, чтобы вернуться к каким-то старым делам. На этот раз ничто не помешает вам успешно завершить их, а результат окажется даже лучше, чем можно было ожидать.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет насыщенным. Вам, скорее всего, захочется действовать быстро. Но ситуация требует совсем другого – осторожных, тщательно продуманных шагов. Решения, принятые в спешке, едва ли окажутся верными. Если вы постараетесь сразу реализовать все появившиеся идеи, то можете позже пожалеть об этом. Поддержка близких будет радовать. Благодаря ей вы не растеряетесь в сложный момент, сохраните оптимизм и уверенность в себе. Возможны удачные совпадения, неожиданные подарки, а также романтические сюрпризы, которые запомнятся вам надолго.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Сегодня придется заниматься несколькими делами сразу, и это едва ли вас обрадует. Хотелось бы сосредоточиться на решении самой важной задачи, но это станет возможным лишь к концу дня. А до того времени старайтесь быть особенно внимательными, чтобы ничего не забыть и не перепутать. День будет благоприятным для общения. Вам будет легко ладить с самыми разными людьми. Некоторые Раки смогут подружиться с теми, кто прежде не испытывал к ним симпатии. Не исключено начало головокружительной романтической истории.'
        }
    ],

    Leo: [ //Лев
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'День отлично подойдет для того, чтобы разобраться со старыми проблемами, решить вопросы, долгое время не дававшие покоя и вам, и окружающим. Уже утром вы почувствуете, что способны на многое, и тут интуиция вас не обманет. Лучше начинать с самых важных задач – справиться с ними окажется проще, чем вы думали. Во второй половине дня нужно будет уделить внимание близким, поддержать того, кто оказался в сложной ситуации. Не исключены небольшие разногласия с теми, кто вам дорог. К вечеру все наладится, но несколько напряженных моментов пережить придется.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День хорошо подойдет для делового общения, встреч с людьми, которых вы хотели бы видеть своими союзниками. Нетрудно будет произвести нужное впечатление. Ваши идеи могут поддержать даже те, от кого вы этого совсем не ожидали. Вероятны предложения, касающиеся сотрудничества, новой работы или перспективных бизнес-проектов. Личные отношения не всегда будут складываться гладко. Иногда близкие будут понимать вас неправильно, из-за этого вы можете рассердиться. Но серьезного конфликта не возникнет. Вы найдете способ сгладить острые углы и поднять всем настроение.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Проявите настойчивость, и у вас все получится. Сегодня вам стоит рассчитывать на собственные силы, а не поддержку звезд или помощь кого-то из знакомых. Не отказывайтесь от своих планов, даже если окружающие будут критиковать их. Вы добьетесь даже большего, чем ожидали, если сохраните уверенность в успехе.           Вероятны небольшие семейные разногласия, не исключены и споры с друзьями. В первой половине дня сложно будет не пойти на поводу у эмоций. Вторая же будет гораздо спокойнее, и вам это понравится. Удастся исправить все ошибки, допущенные раньше сгладить все острые углы.'
        }
    ],

    Virgo: [ //Дева
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Забот будет больше, чем обычно. Могут появиться совершенно новые задачи, требующие немедленного решения, и дела, которые нельзя ни отложить, ни поручить кому-то другому. Вы не растеряетесь и не станете волноваться, отлично справитесь со всем. Наверняка пригодится опыт, полученный давным-давно. Окружающие будут благодарны вам за хорошие советы и подсказки. Вторая половина дня принесет совершенно новые идеи. Взяться за реализацию задуманного захочется немедленно. Вы быстро добьетесь успеха благодаря поддержке друзей и других близких людей.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет очень насыщенным и плодотворным. Вы возьметесь за дела, которые долго откладывали, и быстро добьетесь в них успеха. Порой придется решать несколько вопросов сразу, но вы ничего не забудете, не перепутаете и не упустите из виду. Если потребуется помощь, получить ее будет нетрудно: многие встанут на вашу сторону. Удастся не только хорошо проработать, но и отлично провести свободное время. Вечер отлично подойдет для встречи с друзьями или любимым человеком. Некоторых Дев ждут интересные поездки.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'День будет удачной с деловой точки зрения. Он не принесет таких проблем, с которыми вы не смогли бы справиться. Пригодятся находчивость и изобретательность, полезной окажется информация, полученные давным-давно. Люди, прежде сомневавшиеся в ваших талантах, поймут, как сильно ошибались. Вероятны приятные знакомства. Вам нетрудно будет произвести хорошее впечатление, понравиться. А вот верно оценить тех, с кем вы сегодня впервые встретитесь, едва ли сразу удастся. Так что не спешите доверять таким людям.'
        }
    ],

    Libra: [ //Весы
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'День отлично подойдет для того, чтобы взяться за что-то новое, проявить инициативу в делах. У вас многое будет получаться хорошо, и не потребуется много времени, чтобы решить какие-то сложные вопросы. Можно начинать учиться: вы быстро добьетесь первых успехов, разберетесь в том, что казалось сложным. Вероятны перемены к лучшему в личных отношениях. Станет заметно проще ладить с теми, кто вам дорог, а самых близких людей вы будете понимать с полуслова. Вечер отлично подойдет для того, чтобы строить планы.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Подходящий день для того, чтобы учиться чему-то новому, собирать и анализировать информацию, общаться с людьми, чей опыт уже не раз был вам полезен. Не исключены необычные предложения, касающиеся работы или бизнеса. У Весов, которые давно размышляли о том, чтобы сменить сферу деятельности, будет шанс это сделать. Вам будет легко догадаться о желаниях и намерениях окружающих, понять, что у них на уме. Благодаря своей наблюдательности вы можете даже случайно раскрыть чьи-то секреты. Не спешите рассказывать о том, что узнали.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Сосредоточьтесь на решении сложных и важных вопросов: для этого день отлично подойдет. Вам удастся собрать немало полезной информации, причем получите вы ее раньше других. Вряд ли кто-то сможет вас сбить с толку или запутать, да и стоять у вас на пути не захочется никому. Вероятны денежные поступления, в том числе из неожиданных источников. Не спешите тратить полученное: вскоре эти средства пригодятся для какого-то серьезного дела. С точки зрения личных отношений день будет благоприятным. Общение с близкими подарит массу позитивных эмоций. Хорошо пройдут семейные поездки.'
        }
    ],

    Scorpio: [ //Скорпион
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Благоприятный день. Благодаря своей энергии и настойчивости вы добьетесь того, к чему давно стремились. Удача будет сопутствовать самым смелым вашим начинаниям. Воспользуйтесь подходящим моментом и возьмитесь за что-то действительно важное. Возможно, даже проверенные союзники не сразу захотят к вам присоединиться. Но это не беда: вы и в одиночку добьетесь многого. Вероятны небольшие недоразумения, какие-то мелкие потери. Все это не испортит вам настроения. Как бы ни складывались обстоятельства, вы постараетесь сохранить жизнерадостность и оптимизм.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День хорошо подойдет для того, чтобы взяться за серьезные дела. Возможно, вы не сможете завершить их сегодня, но все же успеете многое. Важно не тратить время на пустяки и не отвлекаться. Прислушивайтесь к интуиции: она подскажет, как лучше действовать. Стоит быть внимательнее во всем, что связано с деньгами. Не спешите с покупками и сделками.Во второй половине дня будет возможность отдохнуть немного, отвлечься от забот, побывать на каких-то интересных мероприятиях. Это хорошее время для новых знакомств. Вы встретите людей, общение с которыми подарит массу позитивных эмоций.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'День будет беспокойным. Возможны напряженные моменты, какие-то мелкие неприятности и досадные недоразумения. Старайтесь не волноваться из-за пустяков, сохранять позитивный настрой. Это будет особенно важным в начале дня. Если удастся справиться с эмоциями, то вскоре вы поймете, как изменить ситуацию к лучшему. Вторая половина дня будет благоприятной для работы и учебы. Подойдет это время и для того, чтобы принимать серьезные решения. Вы разберетесь в том, что прежде казалось сложным, не растеряетесь, даже если что-то пойдет не по плану.'
        }
    ],

    Sagittarius: [ //Стрелец
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Подходящий день для важных разговоров, встреч с людьми, поддержка которых вам очень важна. Удастся не только произвести хорошее впечатление, но и рассказать о своих идеях так, что вам немедленно захотят помочь в их осуществлении. Новое знакомство может открыть перед вами заманчивые профессиональные перспективы. Воспользуйтесь моментом и покажите себя с лучшей стороны.Во второй половине захочется отдохнуть. Позвольте себе небольшую паузу, отвлекитесь от забот, найдите дело, которое будет интересно и вам, и вашим близким.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Будьте внимательны. Это не самый простой день, но вы не допустите серьезных ошибок, если не станете торопиться. Старайтесь быть особенно внимательными там, где дело касается денег. Лучше избегать любых необязательных расходов, не покупать вещи, которые вам не особенно нужны.  Возможны необычные встречи, знакомства, которые произведут на вас сильное впечатление. Некоторые Стрельцы смогут пообщаться с теми, о ком прежде много слышали. Легко будет подружиться с теми, кого вы встретили сегодня. Но отношения не всегда будут складываться гладко.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Далеко не все будет складываться так, как хотелось бы, но вы останетесь довольны тем, как сложится день. Появятся хорошие идеи, новые планы, вы сразу приступите к реализации задуманного. Возможны необычные предложения о сотрудничестве. Интуиция подскажет, что на них можно согласиться, и не ошибется. В первой половине дня будет непросто ладить с коллегами: они не всегда будут понимать вас правильно. Пройдет немного времени, и вы все же найдете способ с ними договориться. Личные отношения будут складываться гармонично в течение всего дня.'
        }
    ],

    Capricorn: [ //Козерог
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Напряженных моментов сегодня едва ли удастся избежать, но вы преодолеете все трудности. Жизненный опыт наверняка пригодится, но еще важнее будет интуиция. Именно благодаря ей вы поймете, как стоит вести себя с новыми знакомыми и что предпринять, чтобы поддержать близких. Пригодится умение предвидеть поступки других и правильно оценивать возможные последствия собственных действий. Удачно сложатся поездки, особенно деловые. Вдали от дома будет шанс заключить выгодные сделки. Не исключены и интересные предложения о работе.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет очень благоприятным для общения. Вы легко поладите с самыми разными людьми, произведете хорошее впечатление на тех, с кем встретитесь впервые. Многим Козерогам сегодня удастся помириться с теми, с кем они раньше были в ссоре. Личные отношения, прежде складывавшиеся напряженно, станут более гармоничными. Вероятны важные новости, касающиеся работы, – они вас обрадуют. Не исключены выгодные сделки, денежные поступления из неожиданных источников. Самые настойчивые представители знака смогут подняться по карьерной лестнице.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'День будет насыщенным. Не захочется сидеть без дела, вы с энтузиазмом возьметесь за решение сложных задач. Волноваться по пустякам вы не станете, сосредоточитесь на том, что действительно важно. На окружающих это произведет наилучшее впечатление. Многие захотят с вами сотрудничать, предложат помощь в реализации ваших идей. Удачно решатся финансовые вопросы. День сложится особенно хорошо для Козерогов, работа которых связана с деньгами, расчетами, планированием бюджета. Но и к остальным представителям знака звезды будут благосклонны.'
        }
    ],

    Aquarius: [ //Водолей
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Забот сегодня наверняка будет значительно больше, чем вы ожидали. Не исключено, что придется исправлять чужие ошибки или доделывать то, что другие начали и бросили на полпути. Это едва ли покажется вам особенно интересным. Но вы постараетесь справиться как можно лучше, и это удастся. Возможны хорошие новости. Скорее всего, они окажутся важными и для вас, и для ваших близких. Вторая половина дня будет особенно щедрой на приятные сюрпризы, неожиданные события, поднимающие настроение. Много поводов для радости будет у влюбленных Водолеев.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет насыщенным и интересным. Вы не станете тратить время напрасно, сделаете много полезного и для себя, и для других. Удастся найти общий язык с теми, с кем вы раньше не ладили. Не исключено, что у вас появятся новые помощники и союзники. Вскоре они станут вашими настоящими друзьями. Ваши лидерские качества сегодня будут проявляться особенно ярко. Легко будет собрать команду единомышленников, убедить людей следовать за вами. Благодаря поддержке новых знакомых вы быстро реализуете какие-то отличные идеи.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Ладить с окружающими не всегда будет просто. Разногласия будут возникать чаще, чем обычно, возможны споры из-за пустяков, да и просто напряженных моментов будет достаточно. Постарайтесь не раздражаться. Вы найдете способ изменить ситуацию к лучшему, если сохраните спокойствие. Вы добьетесь многого, если будете действовать самостоятельно. Не бойтесь сложных дел: сегодня вы наверняка справитесь с ними. Вторая половина дня подойдет для учебы и творчества, занятий, позволяющих дать волю фантазии. Появятся хорошие идеи, в реализации которых помогут близкие.'
        }
    ],

    Pisces: [ //Рыбы
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'В начале дня будет возможность сосредоточиться именно на тех делах, которые вас особенно интересовали в последнее время. Никто не станет отвлекать вас, поэтому нужных результатов вы добьетесь быстро. Поднимет настроение встреча со старыми друзьями, они наверняка поделятся хорошими новостями. Позже наступит подходящее время для учебы, сбора и анализа информации. Вы найдете ответы на вопросы, над которыми много размышляли, и настроение сразу улучшится. Вечер подойдет для общения с самыми близкими людьми.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Вы проявите настойчивость и добьетесь того, к чему давно стремились. Удастся решить сложные задачи, справиться с тем, что другим оказалось не по силам. Деловые переговоры могут пройти напряженнее, чем вы ожидали, но все же завершатся самым благоприятным образом. Некоторые Рыбы найдут очень влиятельных союзников. Стоит быть осторожнее во всем, что связано с деньгами. Не спешите с покупками и сделками. И держитесь подальше от тех, кто обещает золотые горы: сегодня вы можете показаться легкой добычей разнообразным мошенникам.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'В начале дня будет непросто ладить с окружающими, да и с собой вы не всегда будете в ладу. Эмоциональный фон дня порой будет довольно напряженным. Постарайтесь настроиться на позитивный лад, ищите поводы для радости: их будет достаточно. Вторая половина дня обещает интересные встречи, знакомства, которые запомнятся вам надолго. Вы узнаете много полезного. Новая информация натолкнет на интересные мысли, подскажет, на чем сосредоточиться в первую очередь. Вечер будет особенно благоприятным для влюбленных Рыб.'
        }
    ],


}

//событие по кнопки Enter и проверка на даты в соответствии знакаов зодиака
infoDate.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        if (infoDate.value >= '03-21' && infoDate.value <= '04-19') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Aries';
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '04-20' && infoDate.value <= '05-20') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Taurus';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Taurus[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '05-21' && infoDate.value <= '06-21') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Gemini';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Gemini[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '06-22' && infoDate.value <= '07-22') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Cancer';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Сancer[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '07-23' && infoDate.value <= '08-22') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Leo';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Leo[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '08-23' && infoDate.value <= '09-22') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Virgo';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Virgo[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '09-23' && infoDate.value <= '10-23') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Libra';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Libra[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '10-24' && infoDate.value <= '11-21') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Scorpius';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Scorpio[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '11-22' && infoDate.value <= '12-21') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Sagittarius';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Sagittarius[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '12-22' && infoDate.value <= '01-19') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Capricornus';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Capricorn[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '01-20' && infoDate.value <= '02-18') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Aquarius';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Aquarius[0].horoscopeForToday
        } else if (infoDate.value >= '02-19' && infoDate.value <= '03-20') {
            znakZodiac.textContent = 'Pisces';
            todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Pisces[0].horoscopeForToday;
        }
    }
});


//проверяем на состояние радиокнопки 
button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (infoHoroscop1.checked === true){
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Pisces[0].horoscopeYesterday;
    } else if (infoHoroscop2.checked === true){
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Pisces[0].horoscopeForToday
    } else if(infoHoroscop3.checked === true){
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Pisces[0].horoscopeForTomorrow
    }
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');


.inputer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.cheked{
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: start; */
    flex-direction: column;
}

label{
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: start; */
    justify-content: column;
}

input{
    width: 24%;
    height: 32%;
    padding: 20px;
    font-style: 20px;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 3px double #605a8a;
}

INPUT[type="text"]{
    color: #2b2073;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.znakZodiac{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 }

 .day-info{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="inputer">
            <input class="info-date" value="" placeholder="введите год рождения в формате мм-дд-гг">
        </div>
        <div class="cheked">
            <p> <input type="radio" name="name" id="info1"> вчера</p>
            <p> <input type="radio" name="name" id="info2"> сегодня</p>
            <p> <input type="radio" name="name" id="info3"> завтра</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="button-horoscope">
            <button>click</button>
        </div>
        <p class="znakZodiac"></p>
        <p class="today-info"></p>
        <p class="yesterday-info"></p>
        <p class="tomorrow-info"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример реализации события изменения состояния радиобаттона.
Основное: Каждому добавлено значение(value) и назначен слушатель.

```js
'use strict';

let infoDate = document.querySelector('.info-date'); //получние месяца и дня
let znakZodiac = document.querySelector('.znakZodiac'); //знак зодиака

let todayInfo = document.querySelector('.today-info'); //гороскоп на текущий день
let yesterdayInfo = document.querySelector('.yesterday-info'); //гороскоп вчерашнего дня
let tomorrowInfo = document.querySelector('.tomorrow-info'); //гороскоп на завтрашений день

let rbCheck = 2;
const accordance = {
    1: 'horoscopeYesterday',
    2: 'horoscopeForToday',
    3: 'horoscopeForTomorrow'
}
const checkBox = document.getElementsByName('name');
checkBox.forEach(item => {
    item.onclick = function () {
        rbCheck = this.value;
        render();
    }
})

//объект с гороскопом на вчера, завтра, сегодня,
let horoscopesObject = {
    Aries: [//Овен
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Вы быстро справитесь со сложными делами. Браться за них стоит как можно раньше, ведь именно утром поддержка звезд будет особенно заметной. Наверняка найдутся люди, готовые помочь вам, поделиться опытом или подсказать, как лучше действовать. Вероятны предложения о сотрудничестве. Если их сделают те, с кем вы прежде уже работали, можно ответить согласием без долгих раздумийДень обещает приятные знакомства.Будет возможность увидеться с теми, о ком вы раньше много слышали.Легко будет произвести хорошее впечатление: просто ведите себя естественно.Едва ли кто- то сможет противостоять вашему обаянию.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет насыщенным, непростым и интересным. Появится много новых дел, и для того, чтобы с ними справиться, вам придется потрудиться. Но никакие преграды не заставят вас бросить начатое, отказаться от задуманного. Настойчивость, которую вы будете проявлять в течение всего дня, привлечет внимание окружающим и очень им понравится. Не исключено, что в конце дня вам предложат что-то интересное. Старайтесь не переутомляться. На вечер лучше не планировать ничего особенно сложного. Отвлекитесь от забот, отдохните немного. Вы сразу почувствуете себя лучше.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Не спешите делиться своими идеями или делать критические замечания, о которых вас не просили. Сегодня особенно важно не говорить лишнего, ведь сказанное может быть использовано против вас. В остальном же день благоприятен. Он обещает приятные сюрпризы и новые возможности. Будет шанс осуществить то, что еще недавно казалось чрезвычайно сложным. Как бы ни были вы заняты сегодня, постарайтесь найти время для общения с близкими. Участвуйте в семейных делах, старайтесь поддерживать родственников, которые в этом нуждаются.'
        }
    ],

    Taurus: [//Телец
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'День подойдет для новых знакомств, встреч с людьми, на которых вы хотели бы произвести хорошее впечатление. Вы наверняка понравитесь даже тем, кто обычно очень требователен к окружающим, замечает только чужие недостатки. Интуиция подскажет, как правильно провести деловые переговоры, заручиться поддержкой влиятельных людей.  Вероятны денежные поступления, в том числе из неожиданных источников. Не исключены и дорогие подарки. Вечер будет особенно благоприятным для учебы. Вы мгновенно запомните все, что может пригодиться.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Сохраняйте спокойствие, что бы ни происходило вокруг. Этого будет достаточно, чтобы избежать трудностей и неприятностей, а также горячих споров, которые могли бы испортить отношения с окружающими. Действуйте осторожно, старайтесь не спешить. Позже вы не раз похвалите себя за предусмотрительность, проявленную сегодня.Важна разборчивость в контактах. Не доверяйте всем подряд. Делиться важной информацией стоит только с самыми близкими людьми. Именно они поддержат вас и придут на помощь, если потребуется.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Вас ждет беспокойный день. Лучше не рассчитывать на легкие успехи. Скорее всего, вам придется приложить усилия, чтобы достичь нужных результатов. Настойчивость будет особенно важна для тех, кто сегодня возьмется за что-то новое. Таким Тельцам придется не только преодолевать преграды, но и учиться на ходу. Будет непросто, но все получится. Хорошо пройдут деловые встречи, вы быстро поладите с потенциальными партнерами. Нетрудно будет и найти общий язык с близкими. Перемены к лучшему в романтических отношениях станут возможными, если вы проявите инициативу.'
        }
    ],

    Gemini: [//Близнецы
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Будет возможность взяться за интересное дело, к которому долго не получалось приступить. Сегодня обстоятельства сложатся удачно, у вас будет достаточно времени, не возникнет непреодолимых преград, никто не станет вам мешать. Заметных успехов добьются Близнецы, которые занимаются коммерческой деятельностью: вероятны выгодные покупки и сделки. В первой половине дня стоит действовать быстро, а вот во второй лучше не горячиться и не спешить. Это время хорошо подойдет для семейных дел, общения с близкими. Можно принимать гостей.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Не стоит принимать всерьез мелкие недоразумения, которые могут возникнуть в начале дня. Ладить с окружающими в это время будет непросто, но вы не поддадитесь на провокации и найдете способ разрядить обстановку. Появятся неплохие идеи, касающиеся работы. Уже во второй половине дня вы сможете приступить к их реализации. Будет возможность исправить ошибки, допущенные раньше. Справившись с этим, вы почувствуете себя гораздо увереннее и свободнее. Вечер обещает приятное знакомство, которое может получить романтическое продолжение.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'День может показаться довольно утомительным. Вам придется заниматься и своими, и чужими делами, решать проблемы, возникшие по вине других людей. Нелегко придется Близнецам, которые привыкли действовать по-своему, ничего не объясняя и ни с кем не советуясь. Таким представителям знака нужно быть особенно терпеливыми с окружающими. Только так они смогут избежать конфликтов и споров. Первая половина дня будет довольно напряженной, вторая принесет хорошие новости. Скорее всего, они будут связаны с вашей личной жизнью.'
        }
    ],

    Сancer: [//Рак
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Сегодня вам предстоит заниматься чем-то новым и необычным. Учиться придется на ходу, причем совершенно самостоятельно: едва ли кто-то направит вас на верный путь, даст полезный совет или подскажет, как лучше действовать. Первая половина дня обещает интересное знакомство, встречу с человеком, который вскоре станет вашим другом. Вторая половина дня подойдет для того, чтобы вернуться к каким-то старым делам. На этот раз ничто не помешает вам успешно завершить их, а результат окажется даже лучше, чем можно было ожидать.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет насыщенным. Вам, скорее всего, захочется действовать быстро. Но ситуация требует совсем другого – осторожных, тщательно продуманных шагов. Решения, принятые в спешке, едва ли окажутся верными. Если вы постараетесь сразу реализовать все появившиеся идеи, то можете позже пожалеть об этом. Поддержка близких будет радовать. Благодаря ей вы не растеряетесь в сложный момент, сохраните оптимизм и уверенность в себе. Возможны удачные совпадения, неожиданные подарки, а также романтические сюрпризы, которые запомнятся вам надолго.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Сегодня придется заниматься несколькими делами сразу, и это едва ли вас обрадует. Хотелось бы сосредоточиться на решении самой важной задачи, но это станет возможным лишь к концу дня. А до того времени старайтесь быть особенно внимательными, чтобы ничего не забыть и не перепутать. День будет благоприятным для общения. Вам будет легко ладить с самыми разными людьми. Некоторые Раки смогут подружиться с теми, кто прежде не испытывал к ним симпатии. Не исключено начало головокружительной романтической истории.'
        }
    ],

    Leo: [//Лев
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'День отлично подойдет для того, чтобы разобраться со старыми проблемами, решить вопросы, долгое время не дававшие покоя и вам, и окружающим. Уже утром вы почувствуете, что способны на многое, и тут интуиция вас не обманет. Лучше начинать с самых важных задач – справиться с ними окажется проще, чем вы думали. Во второй половине дня нужно будет уделить внимание близким, поддержать того, кто оказался в сложной ситуации. Не исключены небольшие разногласия с теми, кто вам дорог. К вечеру все наладится, но несколько напряженных моментов пережить придется.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День хорошо подойдет для делового общения, встреч с людьми, которых вы хотели бы видеть своими союзниками. Нетрудно будет произвести нужное впечатление. Ваши идеи могут поддержать даже те, от кого вы этого совсем не ожидали. Вероятны предложения, касающиеся сотрудничества, новой работы или перспективных бизнес-проектов. Личные отношения не всегда будут складываться гладко. Иногда близкие будут понимать вас неправильно, из-за этого вы можете рассердиться. Но серьезного конфликта не возникнет. Вы найдете способ сгладить острые углы и поднять всем настроение.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Проявите настойчивость, и у вас все получится. Сегодня вам стоит рассчитывать на собственные силы, а не поддержку звезд или помощь кого-то из знакомых. Не отказывайтесь от своих планов, даже если окружающие будут критиковать их. Вы добьетесь даже большего, чем ожидали, если сохраните уверенность в успехе.           Вероятны небольшие семейные разногласия, не исключены и споры с друзьями. В первой половине дня сложно будет не пойти на поводу у эмоций. Вторая же будет гораздо спокойнее, и вам это понравится. Удастся исправить все ошибки, допущенные раньше сгладить все острые углы.'
        }
    ],

    Virgo: [//Дева
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Забот будет больше, чем обычно. Могут появиться совершенно новые задачи, требующие немедленного решения, и дела, которые нельзя ни отложить, ни поручить кому-то другому. Вы не растеряетесь и не станете волноваться, отлично справитесь со всем. Наверняка пригодится опыт, полученный давным-давно. Окружающие будут благодарны вам за хорошие советы и подсказки. Вторая половина дня принесет совершенно новые идеи. Взяться за реализацию задуманного захочется немедленно. Вы быстро добьетесь успеха благодаря поддержке друзей и других близких людей.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет очень насыщенным и плодотворным. Вы возьметесь за дела, которые долго откладывали, и быстро добьетесь в них успеха. Порой придется решать несколько вопросов сразу, но вы ничего не забудете, не перепутаете и не упустите из виду. Если потребуется помощь, получить ее будет нетрудно: многие встанут на вашу сторону. Удастся не только хорошо проработать, но и отлично провести свободное время. Вечер отлично подойдет для встречи с друзьями или любимым человеком. Некоторых Дев ждут интересные поездки.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'День будет удачной с деловой точки зрения. Он не принесет таких проблем, с которыми вы не смогли бы справиться. Пригодятся находчивость и изобретательность, полезной окажется информация, полученные давным-давно. Люди, прежде сомневавшиеся в ваших талантах, поймут, как сильно ошибались. Вероятны приятные знакомства. Вам нетрудно будет произвести хорошее впечатление, понравиться. А вот верно оценить тех, с кем вы сегодня впервые встретитесь, едва ли сразу удастся. Так что не спешите доверять таким людям.'
        }
    ],

    Libra: [//Весы
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'День отлично подойдет для того, чтобы взяться за что-то новое, проявить инициативу в делах. У вас многое будет получаться хорошо, и не потребуется много времени, чтобы решить какие-то сложные вопросы. Можно начинать учиться: вы быстро добьетесь первых успехов, разберетесь в том, что казалось сложным. Вероятны перемены к лучшему в личных отношениях. Станет заметно проще ладить с теми, кто вам дорог, а самых близких людей вы будете понимать с полуслова. Вечер отлично подойдет для того, чтобы строить планы.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Подходящий день для того, чтобы учиться чему-то новому, собирать и анализировать информацию, общаться с людьми, чей опыт уже не раз был вам полезен. Не исключены необычные предложения, касающиеся работы или бизнеса. У Весов, которые давно размышляли о том, чтобы сменить сферу деятельности, будет шанс это сделать. Вам будет легко догадаться о желаниях и намерениях окружающих, понять, что у них на уме. Благодаря своей наблюдательности вы можете даже случайно раскрыть чьи-то секреты. Не спешите рассказывать о том, что узнали.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Сосредоточьтесь на решении сложных и важных вопросов: для этого день отлично подойдет. Вам удастся собрать немало полезной информации, причем получите вы ее раньше других. Вряд ли кто-то сможет вас сбить с толку или запутать, да и стоять у вас на пути не захочется никому. Вероятны денежные поступления, в том числе из неожиданных источников. Не спешите тратить полученное: вскоре эти средства пригодятся для какого-то серьезного дела. С точки зрения личных отношений день будет благоприятным. Общение с близкими подарит массу позитивных эмоций. Хорошо пройдут семейные поездки.'
        }
    ],

    Scorpio: [//Скорпион
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Благоприятный день. Благодаря своей энергии и настойчивости вы добьетесь того, к чему давно стремились. Удача будет сопутствовать самым смелым вашим начинаниям. Воспользуйтесь подходящим моментом и возьмитесь за что-то действительно важное. Возможно, даже проверенные союзники не сразу захотят к вам присоединиться. Но это не беда: вы и в одиночку добьетесь многого. Вероятны небольшие недоразумения, какие-то мелкие потери. Все это не испортит вам настроения. Как бы ни складывались обстоятельства, вы постараетесь сохранить жизнерадостность и оптимизм.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День хорошо подойдет для того, чтобы взяться за серьезные дела. Возможно, вы не сможете завершить их сегодня, но все же успеете многое. Важно не тратить время на пустяки и не отвлекаться. Прислушивайтесь к интуиции: она подскажет, как лучше действовать. Стоит быть внимательнее во всем, что связано с деньгами. Не спешите с покупками и сделками.Во второй половине дня будет возможность отдохнуть немного, отвлечься от забот, побывать на каких-то интересных мероприятиях. Это хорошее время для новых знакомств. Вы встретите людей, общение с которыми подарит массу позитивных эмоций.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'День будет беспокойным. Возможны напряженные моменты, какие-то мелкие неприятности и досадные недоразумения. Старайтесь не волноваться из-за пустяков, сохранять позитивный настрой. Это будет особенно важным в начале дня. Если удастся справиться с эмоциями, то вскоре вы поймете, как изменить ситуацию к лучшему. Вторая половина дня будет благоприятной для работы и учебы. Подойдет это время и для того, чтобы принимать серьезные решения. Вы разберетесь в том, что прежде казалось сложным, не растеряетесь, даже если что-то пойдет не по плану.'
        }
    ],

    Sagittarius: [//Стрелец
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Подходящий день для важных разговоров, встреч с людьми, поддержка которых вам очень важна. Удастся не только произвести хорошее впечатление, но и рассказать о своих идеях так, что вам немедленно захотят помочь в их осуществлении. Новое знакомство может открыть перед вами заманчивые профессиональные перспективы. Воспользуйтесь моментом и покажите себя с лучшей стороны.Во второй половине захочется отдохнуть. Позвольте себе небольшую паузу, отвлекитесь от забот, найдите дело, которое будет интересно и вам, и вашим близким.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Будьте внимательны. Это не самый простой день, но вы не допустите серьезных ошибок, если не станете торопиться. Старайтесь быть особенно внимательными там, где дело касается денег. Лучше избегать любых необязательных расходов, не покупать вещи, которые вам не особенно нужны.  Возможны необычные встречи, знакомства, которые произведут на вас сильное впечатление. Некоторые Стрельцы смогут пообщаться с теми, о ком прежде много слышали. Легко будет подружиться с теми, кого вы встретили сегодня. Но отношения не всегда будут складываться гладко.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Далеко не все будет складываться так, как хотелось бы, но вы останетесь довольны тем, как сложится день. Появятся хорошие идеи, новые планы, вы сразу приступите к реализации задуманного. Возможны необычные предложения о сотрудничестве. Интуиция подскажет, что на них можно согласиться, и не ошибется. В первой половине дня будет непросто ладить с коллегами: они не всегда будут понимать вас правильно. Пройдет немного времени, и вы все же найдете способ с ними договориться. Личные отношения будут складываться гармонично в течение всего дня.'
        }
    ],

    Capricorn: [//Козерог
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Напряженных моментов сегодня едва ли удастся избежать, но вы преодолеете все трудности. Жизненный опыт наверняка пригодится, но еще важнее будет интуиция. Именно благодаря ей вы поймете, как стоит вести себя с новыми знакомыми и что предпринять, чтобы поддержать близких. Пригодится умение предвидеть поступки других и правильно оценивать возможные последствия собственных действий. Удачно сложатся поездки, особенно деловые. Вдали от дома будет шанс заключить выгодные сделки. Не исключены и интересные предложения о работе.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет очень благоприятным для общения. Вы легко поладите с самыми разными людьми, произведете хорошее впечатление на тех, с кем встретитесь впервые. Многим Козерогам сегодня удастся помириться с теми, с кем они раньше были в ссоре. Личные отношения, прежде складывавшиеся напряженно, станут более гармоничными. Вероятны важные новости, касающиеся работы, – они вас обрадуют. Не исключены выгодные сделки, денежные поступления из неожиданных источников. Самые настойчивые представители знака смогут подняться по карьерной лестнице.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'День будет насыщенным. Не захочется сидеть без дела, вы с энтузиазмом возьметесь за решение сложных задач. Волноваться по пустякам вы не станете, сосредоточитесь на том, что действительно важно. На окружающих это произведет наилучшее впечатление. Многие захотят с вами сотрудничать, предложат помощь в реализации ваших идей. Удачно решатся финансовые вопросы. День сложится особенно хорошо для Козерогов, работа которых связана с деньгами, расчетами, планированием бюджета. Но и к остальным представителям знака звезды будут благосклонны.'
        }
    ],

    Aquarius: [//Водолей
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'Забот сегодня наверняка будет значительно больше, чем вы ожидали. Не исключено, что придется исправлять чужие ошибки или доделывать то, что другие начали и бросили на полпути. Это едва ли покажется вам особенно интересным. Но вы постараетесь справиться как можно лучше, и это удастся. Возможны хорошие новости. Скорее всего, они окажутся важными и для вас, и для ваших близких. Вторая половина дня будет особенно щедрой на приятные сюрпризы, неожиданные события, поднимающие настроение. Много поводов для радости будет у влюбленных Водолеев.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'День будет насыщенным и интересным. Вы не станете тратить время напрасно, сделаете много полезного и для себя, и для других. Удастся найти общий язык с теми, с кем вы раньше не ладили. Не исключено, что у вас появятся новые помощники и союзники. Вскоре они станут вашими настоящими друзьями. Ваши лидерские качества сегодня будут проявляться особенно ярко. Легко будет собрать команду единомышленников, убедить людей следовать за вами. Благодаря поддержке новых знакомых вы быстро реализуете какие-то отличные идеи.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'Ладить с окружающими не всегда будет просто. Разногласия будут возникать чаще, чем обычно, возможны споры из-за пустяков, да и просто напряженных моментов будет достаточно. Постарайтесь не раздражаться. Вы найдете способ изменить ситуацию к лучшему, если сохраните спокойствие. Вы добьетесь многого, если будете действовать самостоятельно. Не бойтесь сложных дел: сегодня вы наверняка справитесь с ними. Вторая половина дня подойдет для учебы и творчества, занятий, позволяющих дать волю фантазии. Появятся хорошие идеи, в реализации которых помогут близкие.'
        }
    ],

    Pisces: [//Рыбы
        {
            horoscopeYesterday: 'В начале дня будет возможность сосредоточиться именно на тех делах, которые вас особенно интересовали в последнее время. Никто не станет отвлекать вас, поэтому нужных результатов вы добьетесь быстро. Поднимет настроение встреча со старыми друзьями, они наверняка поделятся хорошими новостями. Позже наступит подходящее время для учебы, сбора и анализа информации. Вы найдете ответы на вопросы, над которыми много размышляли, и настроение сразу улучшится. Вечер подойдет для общения с самыми близкими людьми.',
            horoscopeForToday: 'Вы проявите настойчивость и добьетесь того, к чему давно стремились. Удастся решить сложные задачи, справиться с тем, что другим оказалось не по силам. Деловые переговоры могут пройти напряженнее, чем вы ожидали, но все же завершатся самым благоприятным образом. Некоторые Рыбы найдут очень влиятельных союзников. Стоит быть осторожнее во всем, что связано с деньгами. Не спешите с покупками и сделками. И держитесь подальше от тех, кто обещает золотые горы: сегодня вы можете показаться легкой добычей разнообразным мошенникам.',
            horoscopeForTomorrow: 'В начале дня будет непросто ладить с окружающими, да и с собой вы не всегда будете в ладу. Эмоциональный фон дня порой будет довольно напряженным. Постарайтесь настроиться на позитивный лад, ищите поводы для радости: их будет достаточно. Вторая половина дня обещает интересные встречи, знакомства, которые запомнятся вам надолго. Вы узнаете много полезного. Новая информация натолкнет на интересные мысли, подскажет, на чем сосредоточиться в первую очередь. Вечер будет особенно благоприятным для влюбленных Рыб.'
        }
    ],

}
/// accordance
function render() {
    if (infoDate.value >= '03-21' && infoDate.value <= '04-19') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Aries';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Aries[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '04-20' && infoDate.value <= '05-20') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Taurus';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Taurus[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '05-21' && infoDate.value <= '06-21') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Gemini';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Gemini[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '06-22' && infoDate.value <= '07-22') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Cancer';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Сancer[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '07-23' && infoDate.value <= '08-22') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Leo';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Leo[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '08-23' && infoDate.value <= '09-22') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Virgo';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Virgo[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '09-23' && infoDate.value <= '10-23') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Libra';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Libra[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '10-24' && infoDate.value <= '11-21') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Scorpius';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Scorpio[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '11-22' && infoDate.value <= '12-21') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Sagittarius';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Sagittarius[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '12-22' && infoDate.value <= '01-19') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Capricornus';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Capricorn[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '01-20' && infoDate.value <= '02-18') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Aquarius';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Aquarius[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    } else if (infoDate.value >= '02-19' && infoDate.value <= '03-20') {
        znakZodiac.textContent = 'Pisces';
        todayInfo.textContent = horoscopesObject.Pisces[0][accordance[rbCheck]];
    }
}

//событие по кнопки Enter и проверка на даты в соответствии знкаов зодиака
infoDate.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        render();
    }
});
```

```css
.inputer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.cheked{
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: start; */
    flex-direction: column;
}

label{
    display: flex;
    /* justify-content: start; */
    justify-content: column;
}

input{
    width: 24%;
    height: 32%;
    padding: 20px;
    font-style: 20px;
    border: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 3px double #605a8a;
}

INPUT[type="text"]{
    color: #2b2073;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.znakZodiac{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 }

 .day-info{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="inputer">
            <input class="info-date" value="" placeholder="введите год рождения в формате мм-дд-гг">
        </div>
        <div class="cheked">
            <p> <input type="radio" name="name" id="info1" value='1'> вчера</p>
            <p> <input type="radio" name="name" id="info2" value='2'> сегодня</p>
            <p> <input type="radio" name="name" id="info3" value='3'> завтра</p> 
        </div>
        <p class="znakZodiac"></p>
        <p class="today-info"></p>
        <p class="yesterday-info"></p>
        <p class="tomorrow-info"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```